# Get number of results from Search Action on Zapier

Tags: search, zapier, zapier-cli

I build zap using zapier, which performs "Find Person" Action on Pipedrive crm (the question is relevant to search in any integration)

The result returned from the search is a **single object**. (Contrary to what might be expected - an array of objects)

My goal is to know **how many records returned from the search** (I mean the list length actually), and use that information to perform various actions later in the Zap.

How can this be done?
[how my zap currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPKo7.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Zapier searches are designed to resolve a piece of info (like an email) into a single record from an external service (like a "Contact"), so it's working as expected here.

I'm not sure the official integration will return the data you want here, but you can write a custom integration that has an action like "Count People Matching Search", which could return that data for you.

There's info about building a custom integration here: https://platform.zapier.com/